# A VB button that lets you choose a local directory

Tags: vb.net, winforms, file-io, directory

In html it's easy to get a button to get an file on your local hard drive but I can't seem to find or remember how to do it for a VB application (using Visual Basic 2010). What I would like is for the button to find a local directory, select it and then add the address to a textbox.

If you have the answer please post below, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) component.

Comment: At first it was hard to get but now it works, thanks. I'll tick it in a min.